# Python - Group by unique value of a column and transpose df to lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, transpose

I am trying to transform a data frame into lists, group by unique value in a column and transpose. I am not sure if I should delete duplicate values first. It looks like I need to use a for loop or pandas to do it but I have not figured out how. It'd be great if someone can help. Here is want I want to do:

Data frame in cvs:

```
Col1    Col2
Apple   Mary  
Apple   Ben
Apple   Katy
Kiwi    Joy
Kiwi    Sam
Banana  Ben
Banana  Tom
Banana  John
```

Desired output:

```
[Apple, Mary, Ben , Katy]
[Kiwi, Joy, Sam]
[Banana, Ben, Tom, John]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of lists

```
l = [[label] + grp['Col2'].unique().tolist() for label, grp in df.groupby('Col1')]


[['Apple', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'Katy'],
 ['Banana', 'Ben', 'Tom', 'John'],
 ['Kiwi', 'Joy', 'Sam']]
```

To access individual list

```
print(l[0])

['Apple', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'Katy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.loc`. For example:

```
for fruits in d_f.Col1.unique():
    names = d_f.loc[d_f['Col1']==fruits,"Col2"].tolist()
    print([fruits]+names)
```